# How to receive touches on UIPickerview using viewForRow delegate?

Tags: iphone, ios7, uipickerview

Could anyone help me out. I'm trying to implement multiple selection on UIPickerview(in iOS 7). With few references from the stack overflow ,i have done as below,

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row   forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view {

    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)view;

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil];
        [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [cell setBounds: CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.frame.size.width -20 , 44)];
        cell.tag = row;       
        cell.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

        UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(toggleSelection:)];
        singleTapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
        singleTapGestureRecognizer.delegate= self;
        [cell addGestureRecognizer:singleTapGestureRecognizer];
        [self.doorSelectionPickerView addGestureRecognizer:singleTapGestureRecognizer];
    }

    //TO DO FOR CHECKMARK    

    cell.textLabel.text = @"1";

    return cell;
}
```

After trying this, its not receiving the tap gesture, and thus `toggleSelection` method is not invoked.

Note: UIpickerview is given as input view of UITextField

```
userSafeDoorTextfeild.inputView = [self doorSelectionPickerView];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue and could help someone who are in this troubled situation.

```
-(UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:
 (NSInteger)row  forComponent:(NSInteger)component 
 reusingView:(UIView *)view {
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil];
    [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [cell setBounds: CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.frame.size.width -20 , 44)];
    cell.tag = row;
    cell.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    UITapGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                          initWithTarget:self action:@selector(showTimePicker:)];
    [recognizer setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
    [recognizer setDelegate:self];


    if(pickerView.tag == DOORSELECTION_PICKER_TAG){
        NSLog(@"its door selection category");
        *[pickerView addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];*
    }
}

 }
```

Instead of adding the tap gesture to the class scope picker view, add the gesture to this  method  picker view object returned in  viewForRow delegate method after checking the tag.